# conda install UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, conda

When I run the command `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`, I encounter this error.

```
matin:(all-in-one)~/ conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matin/Programs/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1129, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

      ...

      File "/home/matin/Programs/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/gateways/disk/read.py", line 147, in read_package_metadata
        data = json.loads(f.read())
      File "/home/matin/Programs/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
        (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

`$ /home/matin/Programs/miniconda3/bin/conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`
```

I tried deleting the environment and recreating it, I also installed `anaconda-clean` and cleaned using it.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

It was caused because my laptop's HDD got some issues (4 months ago, the live ubuntu USB that I was installing from it, was pulled out during moving partitions). So some of my anaconda files have been broken.

for example my `.../miniconda3/pkgs/requests-oauthlib-1.3.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0/info/link.json` file was something like this

```
ÿ¢xeÿ¢xeÿ¢xeÿ¢xeÿ¢xeÿ¢xeÿ£xeÿ£weÿ£weÿ£xeÿ£xeÿ£xeÿ£xeÿ¢xeÿ¢xeÿ¢xeÿ¢xeÿ£xfÿ£x
```

## Solution

This solution worked for me to identify the broken files.

1. Put `print(path)` in the `read.py` file (line 143) on the Traceback, (for mine was in the `/home/matin/Programs/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/gateways/disk/read.py`)
2. Rerun the script to see the paths. for mine was:

```
Preparing transaction: / /home/matin/Programs/miniconda3/pkgs/absl-py-1.3.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0/info/link.json
/home/matin/Programs/miniconda3/pkgs/attrs-22.1.0-pyh71513ae_1/info/link.json
...
/home/matin/Programs/miniconda3/pkgs/google-auth-2.14.1-pyh1a96a4e_0/info/link.json
/home/matin/Programs/miniconda3/pkgs/requests-oauthlib-1.3.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0/info/link.json
failed
```

3. Open the last file using your editor (like vim) to see that it's broken :) (for mine was `/home/matin/Programs/miniconda3/pkgs/requests-oauthlib-1.3.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0/info/link.json`)
4. Remove it using `rm -rf /home/matin/Programs/miniconda3/pkgs/requests-oauthlib-1.3.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0/`

Done!